# Regex ",\\s(.*?),\\s"

Tags: c#, regex

Why regex is not working correctly?

```
string findarg2 = ",\\s(.*?),\\s";

foreach (Match getarg2 in Regex.Matches(tmptwopart, findarg2))
if (getarg2.Success)
{
    for (int m = 1; m < getarg2.Groups.Count; m++)
    {
        int n;
        bool needpointer = false;
        for (n = getarg2.Groups[m].Value.Length - 1; n > -1; n--)
        {
            if (getarg2.Groups[m].Value[n] == ' ')
                break;
            else if (getarg2.Groups[m].Value[n] == '*')
            {
                needpointer = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        n++;

        string part1 = getarg2.Groups[m].Value.Remove(n);
        string part2 = getarg2.Groups[m].Value.Remove(0, n);
        Console.WriteLine(getarg2.Groups[m] + " =->" +part1+ " AND " + part2);
        Console.ReadKey();
        if (needpointer)
        {
            createarglist.Append("<< *(" + part1 + ")" + part2);
        }
        else
        {
            createarglist.Append("<< " + part2);
        }
        createarglistclear.Append(part2+",");
    } }
```

Example enter string:

```
(DWORD code, bool check, float *x1, float *y1, float *x2, float *y2)
```

Output:

```
<< check<< *(float *)y1
```

Expected:

```
<< check<< *(float *)x1<< *(float *)y1<< *(float *)x2
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Need << check<< *(float *)x1<< *(float *)y1<< *(float *)x2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the expression does not work is that it "consumes" the commas: the part that matches `check` also eats up the comma after it, preventing `float *x1` from being matched; same goes with the expression that matches `float *y1`.

Changing the expression to use lookaheads and lookbehinds should work. However, that may not be enough, because the first match would not have a comma in front of it, and the last one will not have a comma after it.

A better expression to use in this case should be this:

```
(?<=[(,])\\s*([^,)]*)\\s*(?=[,)])
```

Here is a complete code example:

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(
    "(DWORD code, bool check, float *x1, float *y1, float *x2, float *y2)"
,   "(?<=[(,])\\s*([^,)]*)\\s*(?=[,)])")
) {
    for (var i = 1 ; i != m.Groups.Count ; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", m.Groups[i]);
    }
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/ln1c0J) producing the six groups as expected:

```
'DWORD code'
'bool check'
'float *x1'
'float *y1'
'float *x2'
'float *y2'
```

Comment: +1 - Good point about the first and last matches. To @FakEFake, in that case make use of the `|` operator within the assertions to allow for more flexible cases. (C# allows for variable-width lookbehinds, so it'll work.)

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're consuming the trailing commas as you go. That is, you already matched the trailing comma, so it's not matched as a leading comma for the next entity you're trying to match. Use zero-width assertions instead:

```
string findarg2 = "(?<=,\\s)(.*?)(?=,\\s)";
```

These are known as "lookbehind" and "lookahead" assertions, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one shot:

```
string input = "(DWORD code, bool check, float *x1, float *y1, float *x2, float *y2)";
string pattern = @"(?:\([^,]*,\s*[^\s,]*\s+([^,]+)|\G),\s+(\S+)\s*( \*)?((?>[^*,)]+))(?>(?=,[^,]+,)|.*)";
string replacement = "$1<< *($2$3)$4";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = "<<" + rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

Comment: @FakEFake: I have forgotten the `@` before the pattern string. Try it now.